# How to make a web page compatible with google chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, cross-browser

I have include Html page into another html page in Dreamweaver using the below code

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">  
$(function(){      
$("#header").load("header.html");  });     
</script>
```

but this code is not  with Google chrome browser. 
Please help me out how to make a web page compatible with Google chrome browser.

Comment: How do you _included_ HTML page into another HTML page?

Comment: What does the Chrome error console say?

Comment: This looks like JQuery; are you including that before this snippet?

Comment: I have created two html pages a.html and b.html. I am including b.html into a.html using the above code. This code working fine with IE and Firefox browser but in Google chrome it is showing the comment(//Header Template) which i put in my html code to include that particular page.

Comment: #Chris- I am not using any snippet i am just using the above code to include my html file into my main html file.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you open this page as local file. For security purpose Goodle Chrome doesnt allow to make AJAX call to local files. To solve this problem you can install the local webserver and open the page using http:// protocol instead of file://

Comment: Where to install the local web server. Please help me out.

Comment: There are a lot of different web servers. You can choose Apache (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_HTTP_Server) for your purpose.

Comment: Hi Alex i have installed the Apache server but i am not able to understand how to use this to preview my page

Comment: Next you need to put your html files under apache document root. After that you can access to your files using http://localhost/ address. You can find additional information on http://lifehacker.com/124212/geek-to-live--how-to-set-up-a-personal-home-web-server or in official apache documentation.

Comment: Hi Alex i have installed the Apache server and put my html files under apache document root and i access those files using local host address but that html files runs in IE not in Google chrome.

Comment: What do you see when open [http://localhost/a.html](http://localhost/a.html) (or another your html file) in the Chrome?

Comment: It shows only comments like//header template but not file which i included using above code.

Comment: Please help me out how to share my files on jsfiddle.net.

Comment: For your situation plnkr.co is more preferable. Open http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=catalogue and then create all your necessary html files in left panel.

Comment: Hi Alex I have created files in plunkr but i didn't get wat's the problem. Will you please tell any other function to include one html page other html page which works.

Comment: The another solutions are using the iframes or server side languages. Can you give me the link to your files on plunkr?

Comment: Hi Alex, I have started web designing 1 month back  so if you don't mind will you share me your email id so that i can send you files because i don't know how to share the links on plunkr. Thanks.

Comment: You can contact me on the facebook (see my profile)